# Adobe flex client-side or server-side

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, client

I am writing a thesis and have been able to place all my frameworks under two categories (client-side frameworks and server-side frameworks), but I can't seem to finf where to place Adobe Flex...
In which category should I place this or should I place it in some separate catgeory?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex is completely client side.  I don't see where the confusion comes from?  I guess it could be server side as well since the original compiler was meant to compile the code when a user accesses the site and then deliver the resulting swf, but that functionality is phased out.

In each case, the result is a client side UI.

Answer (score 3):

Flex lives strongly on the client.  It is a stateful framework which lives in the browser, desktop or mobile devices.  It talks to the backend in the form of data services but unlike the HTML model, markup is not generated on the server but compiled and executed on the client.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The Flex Framework is a client side framework.  What were the specifics that caused you confusion?

It has features for connecting with server side software; but most client side technologies do.